# I can't get to echo images with php

Tags: php, echo

I am trying to echo multiple images but i get the error:

> "PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '?>' in
>   /public_html/View/Pages/Home.php on line 17".

Can you give me any guidance on how to fix it? code below

```
<?php
            for($i=0;$i<$length;$i++)  {
            echo ?><img class="meme-image" src="<?php $meme["$imd_id" == "$i"]->$path?>"><?php
            }
        ?>
```

Comment: `$meme["$imd_id" == "$i"]` doesn't look logical correct..

Comment: @Philipp with this line i try to get every meme image i have in my table. If it doesn't look logical what should i do instead?

Comment: what if images is 5 and loop runs only 3 times ?

Comment: You do a compoarison, which equals to either `true` or `false`, then you try to get the element in the array which has this index, so you try `$meme[false]` and `$meme[true]`. I can guess this is not what you wanted.

Comment: I suppose you wanna have `$meme["imd_id".$i]->$path` or `$meme[$imd_id.$i]->$path`. Depending on what `$img_id` is and/or what the keys in the array `$meme` really look like.

Comment: @Jeff I see your point. The $meme is not array is an object

Comment: then it would be something like `$meme->{["imd_id".$i}->$path` or `$meme->{$imd_id.$i}->$path`. Still, the same issue.

Comment: @sotosbic  show us the output of `var_dump($meme);`. Put it before `for loop` . Also your code have syntax error, so change like this:-`<?php

    var_dump($meme);
 for($i=0;$i<$length;$i++)  {
?>
  <img class="meme-image" src="<?php echo $meme[$i]->$path;?>">
<?php
 }
?>`

Comment: @AlivetoDie--Anantsingh the output is NULL

Comment: when your object us NULL then how's anything will work?Dam man, after so much comments and answers you are telling that input is null

Answer (score 1):

Try By this.

```
<?php
    for($i=0;$i<$length;$i++)  {
        echo '<img class="meme-image" src='.$meme[$imd_id == $i]->$path.' ">';
    }
?>
```

**Note** : You do not require to close php tag. instead of that insert this in php echo.and also you must read [this For best practice.](http://What%20is%20the%20best%20practice%20to%20use%20when%20using%20PHP%20and%20HTML?)

Comment: That might solve his syntax error, but not his problem showing images at all

Comment: i tried your code but instead i got 40 more errors saying for undefined variables for img_id, meme and path and an error "Trying to get property of non-object"

Comment: please post your full code and change question title

Comment: This still contains the expression `$meme["img_id" == "$i"]`, which will cause you trying to access `$meme[true]` or `$meme[false]`, which doesn't make sense.

Comment: @TarangP i can't do that cause the website is in mvc model and it has like 10-15 php files.

Comment: `undefined variables for img_id` this errore mean by that problem is in your query. img id and all other data isn't found. check your query.